# CLOSED TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, boolean, command

Im making a private discord bot and im new to coding. Every time i try to run this command `.balance` it gives me the error: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable`. I dont know what this means and i need help with it. Here is my code:

```
#balance
@client.command(aliases=['bal', 'b'])
async def balance(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  users = await get_bank_data()
  user = ctx.author
  wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]['wallet']
  bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]['bank']
  
  embedbalance = discord.Embed(title = f'''{ctx.author.name}'s balance''',color = 0x00ff00)
  embedbalance.add_field(name = 'Wallet balance:',value = wallet_amt)
  embedbalance.add_field(name = 'Bank balance:',value = bank_amt)

  await ctx.send(embed = embedbalance)
```

Update: When i try to do `.beg` i get the same error to. And it also doesnt upload the .json file. Here is that code:

```
#beg
@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)

  user = ctx.author
  users = await get_bank_data()

  earnings = random.randrange(100)
  embedbeg = discord.Embed(title = f'''Someone gave you {earnings} coins!''',color = 0x00ff00)
  await ctx.send(embed = embedbeg)
  
  users[str(users)]['wallet'] += earnings

  with open('mainbank.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
```

Here is the gat bank data code:

```
async def open_account(user):
  with open('mainbank.json', "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    
  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]['wallet'] = 100
    users[str(user.id)]['bank'] = 0

  with open('mainbank.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json', "r") as f:
      users = json.load(f)
    return True
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is in your `get_bank_data()` function.  Please post that.

Comment: @RoadieRich I updated it! I still cant figure out what is wrong,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `return True` in `get_bank_data`. So when you say

```
users = await get_bank_data()
```

You're setting `users` to the value `True`, which then gives you an error when you ask for `users[str(user.id)]`.

Replace that return statement with

```
return users
```

And your code should work.

Comment: Its fixed, i made a typo in the open_account function. It was unused.